# Wordpress download attribute not forcing PDF download

Tags: html, wordpress, pdf, attributes, custom-wordpress-pages

My site is: https://soundoffsignal.com/resources/

My third link, 2021 Fire Catalog, should automatically download the PDF when you click Download, but it is opening in a new tab.

The HTML looks exactly the same, so I don't know why it is behaving this way.

Comment: Add more info next time when asking questions. It makes life easier for others.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="https://dam-storage.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SoundOff_Signal_Fire_Catalog_2021_072621.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">2021 Fire Catalog – PDF</a>`

Remove target="_blank" from the anchor tag that's causing it open and download in a new tab

Comment: Hmm, that's not working for me, it just makes it open in the same page rather than a new tab, but it still doesn't download automatically.